# Will resigning an app require a new certificate/key pair for signing the server

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm creating an app on behalf of a client which includes push notifications.

I deliver the app to them as an ipa signed with my profiles and they strip those away and resign it with their profiles prior to submitting it to the app store.

I'm trying to determine if this process will stop push notifications from working, and when they re-sign the app they will additionally have to create a certificate/key pair to sign the server with?

Obviously if they change the app-id when they re-sign then a new push certificate will be needed, but if they maintain the same app id would a new push certificate be required? Theoretically I can't see why it would - as the existing push certificate would already be tied to the correct app id and the CSR used in its generation is independent of the CSR used to generate development certificates.

Comment: If you did it with the development certificate, then they will resign it with the production one.is that what you are asking

Comment: No - what I mean is they have their own separate Apple Dev account. I use my account and my profiles to create and deliver the .ipa. They then use their own entirely separate profiles associated with their account to resign it.

Comment: Ok I get it now ,but  I just dont know exactly what you are asking by `new push certificate be required?` You said yourself they use their own so what is the concern?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the key/certificate pair that the server is signed with, not that the app is signed with. My questions wasn't very clear, hadn't had my coffee yet when I wrote it. I've edited the title and content to make it clear its the server side certificate I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it make sense to think that since it using the same `appId` it should work.

However the issue would be the `provisioning profile` since you signed the app with your own.

They will have to do the same , then generate a new pair of `certificate/key` using their `CSR`.

I hope this answers your question.